# C # - .Net Core Write an ANSI encoded text file

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter, ansi, txt

I have to create an ANSI encoded txt file, because the system where I have to load it only reads ANSI and does not read UTF-8. I tried to follow various threads but nothing worked, now my code is this:

```
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
            sw.Write(sb.ToString());
            sw.Close();
            sb.Clear();
```

When I open the generated file in Notepad ++ I see that it is in UTF-8. Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Side note: `File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));` is a shorter version of your code

Comment: Does your text really contains ANSI exclusive characters? Otherwise Notepad++ only makes a guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Notepad++ guesses the encoding based on the file's contents, as text files don't include their used encoding (unless they start with a BOM).

If you write using code page 1252, then that's what's used.

Comment: I tried to upload the file to the system despite notepad ++ giving UTF-8 and it works. Thank you